# Spring Integration HTTP

Tags: spring-integration

Spring Integration HTTP support.
Hi I am trying channel routing based on the path attribute.
For example if the configuration is as follow

I would like to send the message to different channel based on path that is path="gateway/search"  value. Had a look at header based routing and payloadtype routing. Can u please suggest the way to implement.

```
<!-- Inbound/Outbound Channels -->
<int:channel id="ServiceSearchRequest" />
<int:channel id="ServiceSearchResponse" />


<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundEmployeeSearchRequestGateway"
    supported-methods="GET, POST" request-channel="ServiceSearchRequest"
    reply-channel="ServiceSearchResponse"
    mapped-response-headers="Content-Type" 
    path="ieg/Service/search" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-timeout="5000">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="ServiceSearchRequest"
    reply-channel="ServiceSearchResponse"
    url="http://localhost:8080/proj/Service/avgWaitTime123.json"
    http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    mapped-response-headers="Content-Type"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking for; you only have a single `path` (`ieg/dataService/search`) so all messages would go to a single channel if you routed on the path.

If you mean you want to route based on some query string parameter `..?foo=bar` then you can add a `<header/>` element to the inbound gateway to capture it as a header; e.g.

```
<int-http:header name="foo" expression="#requestParams.foo.get(0)" />
```

You can then use a header value router. For a full list of variables available for header expressions, see [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-namespace) (scroll down to `URI Template Variables and Expressions`.